# ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy a cloud function using a compilation via the following step.
The compilation is triggered by Cloud Build.

```
 - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
   args: ['beta', 'functions',
       'deploy', '${_FUNCTION_NAME}',
       '--runtime', 'go111',
       '--region', '${_REGION}',
       '--entry-point', '${_ENTRYPOINT}',
       '--env-vars-file', '.env.${_DEPLOY_ENV}.yaml',
       '--trigger-topic', '${_TRIGGER_TOPIC_NAME}',
       '--timeout', '${_FUNCTION_TIMEOUT}',
       '--service-account', '${_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}',
       '--vpc-connector', 'projects/${_PROJECT_ID}/locations/${_REGION}/connectors/${_VPC_CONNECTOR}']
   dir: '${_FUNCTION_PATH}'
```

I trigger the compilation manually via the GCP Console.

**Result:**

All the previous steps are successful.

But this one ends with this error :

```
Starting Step #9
Step #9: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #9: ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
Step #9:
Step #9: If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
Step #9: gcloud feedback
Step #9:
Step #9: To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
Step #9: gcloud info --run-diagnostics
Finished Step #9
ERROR
ERROR: build step 9 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you check the value of each substitution variables? Where do you have an `items` value? In your `.env.yaml`file? Did you try this command manually to validate it?

Comment: is that your entire build yaml? post the whole thing

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere 1. I checked the variables, they are all correctly filled (cloud build outputs a log with the resovled command) 2. "items" is nowhere into the used file for the compilation. 3. I launched the whole thing with cloud-build-local with success.

Comment: @TravisWebb I'll post the whole compilation file

Comment: After triple checking the whole compilation file and corresponding GCB trigger, it worked fine on Cloud Build With Trigger. Reason : I finally had a divergence between trigger subsitutions and compliation file. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for some reason, your config file was not updated. In order to mitigate the situation you can:

1-Backup your current config file

2-Delete the config file

3-Try running the command once again

Your config file should be at ~.ssh